# Parsing text file

Tags: java, sql, parsing

I am trying to convert this .txt file into SQL queries that I can read into an SQLite Database, problem is that I can't get the information I need printed out when I need it.

The problem from this code is that it will print out when it reaches the prob property, and then print the same line again when it reaches the min/max property, just this time with the correct values found in the file.

There is only 1 item with this ID but it prints twice:

```
0908100 ItemID: 2060000 Prob: 0.108 Min: 1 Max: 1
0908100 ItemID: 2060000 Prob: 0.108 Min: 10 Max: 20
```

The whole file is properly structured so should always follow the same pattern so when it reaches "prob" I have been trying to find a way to check if the next value is min/max and if it isn't print, otherwise print after reading min/max, I haven't been able.

The output I want from the program would be like this when it finds a min/max property:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`drops` (mobID, itemID, prob, min, max);
 VALUES (0908100, 2060000, 0.108, 10, 20);
```

If there is no min/max after prob then the same line should be like this instead:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`drops` (mobID, itemID, prob, min, max)
 VALUES (0908100, 2060000, 0.108, 1, 1);
```

Money will always be itemID 0 with min/max being default to the value of money.
so:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`drops` (mobID, itemID, prob, min, max)
 VALUES (0908100, 0, 0.65, 87, 87);
```

.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int radNmr = 0;
    String mobID = "";
    String money = "";
    String item = "";
    String prob = "";
    String min = "1";
    String max = "1";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Monster_Drops1.txt"));

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String namn = sc.next();
        String namn1 = sc.next();

        if ("m".equals(namn.substring(0, 1)) && !"money".equals(namn) && !"max".equals(namn) && !"min".equals(namn) ) {
            mobID = namn.substring(1);
        }

        switch(namn) {
            case "money":
                money = namn1;
                break;
            case "item":
                item = namn1;
                break;
            case "prob":
                if (!money.equals("")) {
                    money = "";
                    break;
                } else if (money.equals("")){
                    prob = namn1;
                    System.out.println(mobID + " ItemID: " + item + " Prob " + prob + " Min: " + min + " Max: " + max);
                    break;
                }
            case "max":
                if (min.equals("1")) {
                    max = namn1;
                    break;
                } else if (!min.equals("1")) {
                    max = namn1;
                    System.out.println(mobID + " ItemID: " + item + " Prob " + prob + " Min: " + min + " Max: " + max);
                    max = "1";
                    min = "1";
                    break;
                }
            case "min":
                if (max.equals("1")) {
                    min = namn1;
                    break;
                } else if (!max.equals("1")) {
                    min = namn1;
                    System.out.println(mobID + " ItemID: " + item + " Prob " + prob + " Min: " + min + " Max: " + max);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The Monster_Drops1.txt comes in this sort of format, the start/end tags after the monster ID has no relevance and I just added it because of the Scanner throwing errors at me when that line only had one value.

```
m0908100 Start
money 87
prob 0.65
item 2340802
prob 0.4
item 2640002
prob 0.1
item 2040002
prob 0.00003
item 2041001
prob 0.00003
item 2060000
prob 0.54
min 10
max 20
item 9010000
prob 0.98

m0740101 end
money 80
prob 0.55
item 6050000
prob 0.9
item 2041006
prob 0.00003
item 3014000
prob 0.41
```

Comment: You have a mess of `if` and `else if` statements. I suspect that this is your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary debugging techniques. If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I definitely recommend looking into learning a debugger as was suggested by a previous comment.

In the meantime, it looks like the first print statement is printed after this conditional: `else if (namn.equals("prob") && money.equals(""))`. The second print statement is printed after this conditional: `else if (namn.equals("max") && !min.equals("1"))`.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I very much appreciate the fast replies!


And yeaa it's pretty messy, though the code works for the most part of what I am trying to do, it's just that I can't get all the information I need into a single line, I need mobID, item, prob, and if min/max shows up after Prob them too.

I get stuck with the part where min/max comes after prob, I can't read the next line and min/max doesn't appear all the time.

Will definitely look into debugging, but I don't believe that's the problem here, I just don't know how to read all the info into a single line :)

Comment: One more thing, I am honestly not sure how I can make this code shorter without removing the reason this happens, rewriting it into a better solution is not something I have been able to which is why it looks like this, The current code is dependent on these things to produce the output, I know why my problem happens but I have no idea how to fix it :/

Comment: I changed to a switch instead, hopefully it's a bit more readable now :/

Comment: Can you please add to the question what you **want** the output to look like? Because I don't understand the reason for having `if-statements` with "money", if you don't have them in the output...

Comment: Thanks for response! I added it. Basically I have a Database where all itemID's are followed by prob, mobID, min, max, and I need to get this text file to update that DB.  Money counts as its own itemID, and will always be 0, that's where if (!money.equals("")) comes in, when that's true under prob, it should print the query and then reset those values for the next loop

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everone who took the time to help me out, it was very very helpful!

I did find an answer to this problem, and it was rather simple really, I read the file into an ArrayList using a Scanner, and then just modified that Switch to give me the correct output.